# preserve EXIF ( GPS / DateTimeOriginal ) when uploading HEIF image in mobile safari

Tags: ios, safari, heif

It seems the iOS 11 mobile safari will strip some `EXIF` (  GPS / DateTimeOriginal ) when uploading `HEIF` image, how to preserve the EXIF?

Comment: have you found solution to it?

Comment: I'm also interested